# LINQ getting a list from another list of entities

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I have the following EF code-first hierarchy:

1. Markets can have many UserIntervalAlerts
2. UserAlerts have one ApplicationUser

First, I want to check that .Any() markets exist that have UserIntervalAlerts for the current user.

Then, 
I want to get all Markets that have UserIntervalAlerts for the current ApplicationUser

```
if (exchange.Markets.Count(x => x.UserIntervalAlerts?.Select(y => y.User) != GetCurrentUser()) > 0)
                {
                    marketList = marketList.Where(m => m.UserIntervalAlerts.Select(x => x.User) == GetCurrentUser()).ToList();
                }
```

Comment: Please show the code you have that's not working

Comment: `marketList = marketList.Where(market => market.UserIntervalAlerts.Any(userIntervalAlert => userIntervalAlert.User) == GetCurrentUser()).ToList();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you describe, something like this should do what you want.

```
var marketsWithEventsForUser = markets
    .Where(market => market.UserIntervalAlerts
        .Any(alert => alert.User == GetCurrentUser());
if (marketsWithEventsForUser.Any()) 
{
    //iterate over list and do whatever...
}
```

I am assuming that equality will work as you expect it to for `User` and whatever type is returned by `GetCurrentUser()`.

Comment: ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: source
Bombs on .Any()

Comment: My bad. I had to include the UserIntervalAlerts in my obj like this:
"marketList = _context.Markets.Include("UserIntervalAlerts").Where(x => x.Exchange == exchange).ToList();"